# Getting the localized ErrorMessage for RequiredAttribute in EditTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I started with localizing the default model validation error messages by adding a custom resource file and binding *ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider* and *DefaultModelBinder* to this:

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "MyModelValidation";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyModelValidation";
```

Then I discovered that the error message *PropertyValueRequired* only triggers when a property that is non-nullable is missing, so the localized error messages is not showing on for example missing strings. To solve this I could supply the *RequiredAttribute* on the property in question with *ErrorMessageResourceName* and *ErrorMessageResourceType* to have it look up the value in the custom resource file.

To apply this globally for all Required-attributes I did:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter: RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
    public CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelValidation);
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter));
    ...
    }
```

This works fine, except when using a custom datatype for where I have a custom *EditorTemplate*. The *CustomRequiredAttributeAdapter* is not used here, and the only data I can parse out from the *ModelMetaData* supplied to the EditorTemplate is the default English error message.

Why is a custom *RequiredAttributeProvider* not called for a custom datatype? Would it be possible to enable this without having to explicitly set the references to the resource file in the *RequiredAttributes* for custom datatypes?